# Randomized Benchmarking Circuit Generation in pyquil

Tags: clifford-group, randomised-benchmarking, pyquil

The task at hand is to generate randomized benchmarking circuits using a native gate set (e.g. x, y, and iswap) in the easiest way possible.

Have been using qiskit for this purpose but it appears that it does not offer enough flexibility for my needs.

Maybe someone could explain how to do in in PyQuil?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.